# How to wget files from an FTP site without creating any subdirectories?

Tags: wget, ftp

I am trying to download a folder with this command:

```
wget -m -np -nH ftp://user:passwordx@1.1.1.1/FTP/config2all/* -P /home/myuser/
```

But when it is finished downloading, it downloads

```
/home/myuser/FTP/confi2all/Rest_of_folders
```

However, I only want files at the root of the `config2all` directory, not all of the sub-directories.
Is there any way to do this with `wget`?

Answer (score 1):

the `wget` man page to the rescue (`man wget` is your friend):

> ```
>   --level=depth
>       Set the maximum number of subdirectories that Wget will recurse
>       into to depth.  In order to prevent one from accidentally 
>       downloading very large websites when using recursion this is limited
>       to a depth of 5 by default, i.e., it will traverse at most 5
>       directories deep starting from the provided URL.  Set -l 0 or -l inf for infinite recursion depth.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i solve it like this

```
wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=2
```